# Binary operator "&&" cannot be applied to two String operands

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm getting this error...

`Binary operator "&&" cannot be applied to two String operands`

for this line of code...

```
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext
(["color" : newPlay.tColor] && ["match" : newPlay.match])
```

I'm trying to **`updateApplicationContext` with both "color" and "match"**.

*I can't do them separately, or else it only takes the second line of code.
i.e This would only pass `match` but not `color`:*

```
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["color" : newPlay.tColor])
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["match" : newPlay.match])
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And you think that the `&&` operator can somehow magically be used here? Don't you think it might be a good idea to learn just a tiny bit of Swift before trying to write code in it? Like, how to write a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

```
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["color" : newPlay.tColor, "match" : newPlay.match])
```